# Unable to authenticate on WIN10 machine with GSuite APis

Tags: c#, google-api, windows-10, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

In my project I am using Google apis. Its redirecting to web browser for authentication. But on WIN 10 machine where I try to run the same code, its not redirecting to web browser and there is no any error thrown. The user logged in to WIN10 machine is guest user and don't have any admin rights. Same code is working on other operating systems.

What can be the possible settings that I need to change on Win 10 machine?

Here is the sample code.

```
ClientSecrets   _ClientSecret            = null;
_scopes = new[]{GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom};
_ClientSecret                   = new ClientSecrets();
_ClientSecret.ClientId          = m_ClientID;
_ClientSecret.ClientSecret      = m_ClientSecret;
FileDataStore objFileDataStore  = new FileDataStore(m_TokenResponsePath, true);
_userCredentials               = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(_ClientSecret,
                                                        _scopes,p_GAppsUserID,
                                                        System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                                                        objFileDataStore).Result;// Geeting stuck on this statement
```

Comment: sounds like your firewall might be blocking the google auth servers.

Comment: I have disable the firewall but still having same issue.

Comment: sounds like you dont have permission to write to m_TokenResponsePath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to trace out the issue. The admin user of the machine having chrome as default web browser and guest use having IE as default web browser.